# Build fails with simple Haskell library with cabal new-build with GHC 8.6.3

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-platform, cabal-new

Trying to build a Simple library with Haskell.
It worked once and then just stopped working(weirdly)

only a few commands were run,
a simple cabal init with only library

then the following library was added

Greet.hs

```
module Greet where


greeet s = "Hey, " ++ s
```

then cabal new-build was run and then cabal new-repl

the error is as follows

```
Build profile: -w ghc-8.6.3 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - HaskellTry-0.1.0.0 (lib) (ephemeral targets)
Preprocessing library for HaskellTry-0.1.0.0..
GHCi, version 8.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Ok, one module loaded.
Prelude Greet> greeet "h"
"
```

everything is just stuck after that.

Comment: Supposing you are in windows, what version and what console are you using?

Comment: windows 8 with cabal version 2.4.1.0 and ghc version 8.6.3 using the cmd

Comment: Not sure what is going on. saw this video too https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7R-2vtPLDM&t=272s and followed the steps it still didnot work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GHC 8.6.3 on Windows suffers from a [bug](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/16057) that makes it pretty much unusable. The issue should be [solved](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_8_6_4.html#binaries) in 8.6.4.